# Spring cloud stream Kafka creates a weird topic on startup

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have the following setup in application.yml for my Spring cloud stream Kafka:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: userBinding
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          broker: localhost:9092
          replicationFactor: 1
        bindings:
          userBinding-in-0:
            destination: user
```

and the following consumer function to be called:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<UserModel>> userBinding() {
    return message -> {
        System.out.println("Received:" + message);
    };
}
```

For some reason as soon as I start the application it automatically creates a new topic named userBinding-in-0 instead of consuming messages from user topic!

Can you please let me know what I'm missing or setting up incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destination is a common property (not Kafka-specific) and shouldn't be under the `kafka` node.

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        userBinding-in-0:
          destination: user
```